# How do i use useEffect() / useState() hooks here

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React Js and learning to implement certain functionalities by developing a website. Here i need to implement something like this -
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_typewriter but on page load (not on button click)

But as we know that React has Hooks, which needs to be used while implementing functionalities in the project. So i tried to implement Hook, but need some help in using it, I researched some examples on internet but didn't understood and doesn't fit for my current requirement.

Main.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import '../App.css';

const Main = () => {

    useEffect( () => {
        var i = 0;
        var txt = 'Some Text here lorem ipsum lorem ipsum';
        var speed = 50; 
    
        function typeWriter()  {
            if (i < txt.length) {
                document.getElementById("typingText").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
                i++;
                setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
            }
        }
    });

    return(
        <main>

            <div className='row'>                
                <img src='image.png' height='auto' width='100%' alt="banner"/>
                <div className='position-absolute top-50 start-0 translate-middle-y p-5'>
                    <div class="card bg-black" style={{width: '30%'}}>
                        <div class="card-body text-white fw-bold">
                            <h1 id="typingText"></h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </main>
    );

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are missing the array of dependencies of the hook. This prop is extemely important, otherwise the `useEffect` hook will keep on calling, reaching an overflow of calls.

If I understand what you want, every *x* milliseconds the typed text should change. `useEffect` will do the work. In this case, as you want **only to run when the component mounts**, the dependency array of the hook will be empty (`[]`). Inside the hook, you can set up an interval, that keeps running the function that you want. With this brief explanation, you could do:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import '../App.css';

const Main = () => {
    // We will keep track of how many letters are being displayed
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

    const type = () => {
        setIndex((prev) => Math.min(prev + 1, 50));
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const id = setInterval(type, 500);

        // It is important to clear the interval when the component unmounts!
        return () => clearInterval(id);
    }, []); // We are setting an empty dep array

    return (
        <main>
            <div className='row'>
                <img src='image.png' height='auto' width='100%' alt='banner' />
                <div className='position-absolute top-50 start-0 translate-middle-y p-5'>
                    <div class='card bg-black' style={{ width: '30%' }}>
                        <div class='card-body text-white fw-bold'>
                            <h1 id='typingText'>
                                {'Your text'.substring(0, index)}
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    );
};

export default Main;
```

To sum up, what we are doing is:

1. Setting an interval to repeat after 500ms. As commented in the code, it is crucial to clear the interval once the component unmounts. The `setInterval` returns the identifier of the interval, which is used to identify the interval to remove with `clearInterval`.
2. Instead of using the `window` to manipulate the DOM, we keep track of the state, increasing the letters to display from our string.
3. Finally, we "cut" the string displaying from 0 to the current index, which will be incremented every 500ms, creating the typewritter effect.

Hope to have been clear!

> I recommend you take a look at the [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I followed your given code but whole string loads immediately and only last two words of whole string works with Effect.

Comment: I made a version very similar to this using a custom hook, you can have a look here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3ak2ph?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: @mddg I found a mistake in the above code "Math.max()" is used instead of "Math.min()" which leaded to immediately load the text.